# How to convert this mysql table into pivot table?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a table that look like this.

```
ID_ACTIVITY    ID_CLASS    EXEC_VALUE
    ACT_III           A           450
      ACT_I           B           550
     ACT_II           A           750
    ACT_III           B           550
     ACT_II           A           650
      ACT_I           A           750
      ACT_I           B           750
    ACT_III           A           950
    ACT_III           A           150
```

I'd like to create a report based on this table into some kind of pivot table. This should be the report output

```
ID_ACTIVITY     A_COUNT     B_COUNT    AB_SUM
      ACT_I           1           2      2050             
     ACT_II           2        NULL      1500
    ACT_III           3           1      2100
```

Note :

- `A_COUNT` and `B_COUNT` are dynamic based on the value in `ID_CLASS`
- `AB_SUM` is based on the value of `EXEC_VALUE` in each `ID_ACTIVITY` in each `ID_CLASS`

I have done it using PHP, but I wonder is it possible do it in MySQL way and is it faster to generate with around thousand of data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql)

Comment: You do your reporting in the MySQL cli? Oh joy

Comment: @Strawberry yes currently. any better option?

Comment: Well, I'd be tempted to some appliication code for that - e.g. php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id_activity,
    sum(case when id_class = 'A' then 1 end) a_count,
    sum(case when id_class = 'B' then 1 end) b_count,
    sum(exec_value) ab_sum
from mytable
group by id_activity
```

Comment: hi @GMB, if there is a new `ID_CLASS` should I add another condition? or somehow can do it automatically?

Comment: @Shota: no you will need to do it manually by adding another column to the query, with the correct conditional expression (`sum(case ... end)`). For this to be *automatic*, you would need to use dynamic SQL, which is a different beast (and beyond the scope of your initial question).